# Android Studio: emulator does not detect a wifi network

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having a problem with Android Studio; I have created an app to which I have to interact with a device connected via Wi-Fi.

Through a hotspost I created a network with my PC (Windows 10) with its name and password.
When I activate the hotspost from my pc the device is detected; since i have to work on the same network i need to connect the android studio emulator on the same network But I notice that this does not find the network created via hotspost.

If I connect with a smartphone, the network is detected and I connect smoothly, so the problem is in Android Studio.

I tried to browse the internet, but found nothing on this subject.

Can you help me kindly? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the emulator will connect to the same network that the laptop is connected to, so the hotspot created by your laptop will not be visible

Comment: I get it. why is it not seen on the net? because as I said before, only the device is seen and not the emulator

Comment: coz the emulator is an "emulator" ! it's not a physical device ! its connected to the network via the pc, its not connected directly to the network !

Comment: so is the pc that i have to connect on the network?
Since I created the hotspot from the same pc, how can I connect it on the same network? I apologize if I ask these questions, I am a beginner

Comment: asking questions is always good ! I will explain it in a simpler way dont worry !
Your PC is connected to - WIFI-A (Assume)
Your PC Hotspot is named Hotspot-A
All devices are connected to Hotspot-A
The emulator is on the PC, so it is connected to WIFI-A through the PC
So it will not show up on the list of devices connected to WIFI-A since it is connected via the PC

Comment: perfect, now it's clear. Thank you so much